# Represent a image as a matrix matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I represent an image as a matrix in Matlab?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As soon as you've loaded the image into Matlab, it is represented as a matrix. For example

```
>> A = imread('peppers.png');
>> size(A)
ans =
   384   512     3
```

A is a 384-by-512-by-3 array, representing an RGB image, where e.g.  `A(:,:,1)` is the red channel

Comment: @g24l: I personally find that array is the better term

Comment: `it is represented as a matrix` ... you say, which is a nxm array, but the truth is `it is represented as a tensor` which is the correct term for an nxmx3 array. This is a specificity, but the original question is abusing the term.

Comment: @g24l: Indeed I use the term proposed by the OP, and I agree that it matrix is not correct in the strict mathematical sense. However, words do have different meaning in different contexts, and colloquially, arrays are referred to as matrices (or n-d matrices), especially images that are commonly represented in 2D.

Comment: yeap, I agree on using "array" ... but not matrix. The reason is that if you want to load an image as a matrix, then you have to do a representation of the RGB color space to a unique value (not impossible, but not what happens here)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989880/how-to-use-block-processing-for-image).

Basically, start with the `imread` function, and take it from there.

Answer (score 2):

[imread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imread.html) can read your image file as a matrix.